# Can't open .mpk file in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, map-package

I am trying to import .mpk file in ArcMap 10.3.1. But, when I try to open using folder connection, the file with .mpk extension doesn't show up.[image: as shown in figure]. It only shows .tif file but not mpk file.

Comment: drag and drop mpk on arcgis with empty mxd or double click on mpk in Windows explorer

Comment: Or double click on it in explorer (or you equivalent) and hope your Esri file manager is playing nice today. As a map package is a *map package* and not *data* you can't open it with 'add data', it would be more likely to be openable by something in the file menu like File::open then choose "all supported map formats" to see if it shows up there. A map package is essentially a zip file containing (hopefully) all the data and a map document.

Comment: @FelixIP I am able to open it while double-clicking. But, I just want to know why folder connection isn't showing the file.

Comment: Or extract with 7-Zip (http://www.7-zip.org/).... its a compressed "package" of files associated with an mxd.

Comment: If you want to see mxd, you need to unpack it to place of your choice.

Comment: Use package toolbox for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [Map Package `.mpk` file](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/package-map.htm) is *not* data to be added to a map, which is why you can't see it using the Add Data dialog.  It is a package containing different components that can make up your map including the mxd file.

You can [extract](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/extract-package.htm) the contents to a folder and then open it in ArcMap.